# I am getting an error while running yahoo finance module

Tags: python-3.x, yahoo-finance

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
23 # fix_yahoo_finance is used to fetch data
24 import fix_yahoo_finance as yf
---> 25 yf.pdr_override()
26
27 options = " Stock Linear Regression Prediction, Stock Logistic Regression Prediction, Support Vector Regression, Exit".split(",")

TypeError: download() missing 1 required positional argument: 'tickers'

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include the appropriate code.   Do you have Fix-yahoo-finance installed?

Comment: Please include that in your original post and not in the comments.

Comment: I have edited the main question, now this error is showing up!

Comment: You're missing something.  I'm looking at https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance.  You're missing the ```from pandas_datareader import data as pdr``` part; assuming that's the only thing that's different in your code.

Comment: Its not working